# How to change settings variable to be different for every user

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-settings

## MY views.py

```
def change_currency(request):
    settings.CURRENCY = request.POST['currency']
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

## My settings.py

```
CURRENCY = 'EUR'
```

## My form

```
                    <form action="{% url 'change_currency' %}"
                          method="POST" class="currency">
                        EUR
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <input style="display: none" value="EUR" name="currency">
                    </form>
```

## Problem 1

If I manually change the `settings.CURRENCY` variable in everything works like a charm, but if I make a form and try to change the `settings.CURRENCY` it doesn't work

## Problem 2

Will it  be possible to have a variable in `settings.py` that change for different users

## Problem 3

I can't use sessions, beause i use `settings.CURRENCY` in `filters.py` and I don't know how to use `request.session` in `filters.py`

Comment: What is `filters.py`? Per-user settings must be stored in the user's session, you shouldn't even think of using `django.conf.settings` for this. So the only problem I see is your Problem 3, but you need to clarify what you're trying to do because then we might help you to figure out how to access a user's session (or pass the data) from `filter.py`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you [can access request](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#request-based-filtering) and therefore `session` in filter.

The solution you try to use does not work for several reasons.

### Settings are imported once

When you import module object like this into another module (for example `myapp.views`):

```
from settings import CURRENCY
```

the changes done to `settings.CURRENCY` will not be visible in the `views` module. The import happens once and the value at import time is bound to variable in the module.

### Multiple workers

Even if you change the variable in `views` module there is another problem. If you are running non develop server (like gunicorn) it starts several processes to handle requests. It may happen that a change done to settings is processed by one process and the next request is processed by another worker which has the old value.

There should be one place where this settings is stored. Session is a good place as it is global and private to user.

Comment: How can i use the request in custom django filter?